# WP3 and 3D how do you fill the Viewport3D with the VisualBrush?

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, math, 3d

I have a VERY simple 3D space defined in WPF, which defines a single 3D rectangle and a 3D camera. The 3D Rect has a Material of a VisualBrush which depicts the contents of the window.
It works fine(the projection fill the available area nicely) when the window size is larger than 960x550.
BUT, below that number (and as long as the width of the window is considerably smaller than it's height) it leaves a white space on the right of the screen. I would appreciate any advice or directions...

Here is my XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="RootGrid">
        <!--UI Stuff here-->
    </Grid>
    <Viewport3D x:Name="MyAnimatedObject" ClipToBounds="False">
        <Viewport3D.Camera>
            <PerspectiveCamera x:Name="myPerspectiveCamera" FieldOfView="60" Position="0,0,1"/>
        </Viewport3D.Camera>
        <ModelVisual3D>
            <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                <DirectionalLight Color="#FFFFFF" Direction="-0.5,-0.5,-0.5"/>
            </ModelVisual3D.Content>
        </ModelVisual3D>
        <ModelVisual3D>
            <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                <DirectionalLight Color="#FFFFFF" Direction="0.5,-0.5,-0.5"/>
            </ModelVisual3D.Content>
        </ModelVisual3D>
        <ModelVisual3D>
            <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                <GeometryModel3D x:Name="geometryModel3D">
                    <GeometryModel3D.Transform>
                        <Transform3DGroup>
                            <TranslateTransform3D/>
                            <ScaleTransform3D/>
                            <RotateTransform3D/>
                            <TranslateTransform3D/>
                            <TranslateTransform3D/>
                        </Transform3DGroup>
                    </GeometryModel3D.Transform>
                    <GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                        <MeshGeometry3D
       TriangleIndices="0 3 2 0 2 1"
       TextureCoordinates="0,0 1,0 1,1 0,1"
                            Normals="0,0,1 0,0,1 0,0,1 0,0,1"
       Positions="-1,-1,0 1,-1,0 1,1,0 1,1,0 -1,1,0 -1,-1,0"/>
                    </GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                    <GeometryModel3D.Material>
                        <MaterialGroup>
                            <DiffuseMaterial>
                                <DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                                    <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding ElementName=RootGrid}" Stretch="Fill"/>
                                </DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                            </DiffuseMaterial>
                        </MaterialGroup>
                    </GeometryModel3D.Material>
                </GeometryModel3D>
            </ModelVisual3D.Content>
        </ModelVisual3D>
    </Viewport3D>
```

**And the code behind for the dynamic resize of the 3D Rect here:**

```
Private Sub MainWindow_SizeChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.SizeChangedEventArgs) Handles Me.SizeChanged
    Dim AspectRatio As Double = RootGrid.ActualWidth / RootGrid.ActualHeight

    Dim CameraDistance As Double = AspectRatio / Math.Tan(30D * Math.PI / 180)
    myPerspectiveCamera.Position = New Media3D.Point3D(0, 0, CameraDistance)


    Dim points As New Media3D.Point3DCollection
    With points
        .Add(New Media3D.Point3D(0D - AspectRatio, 1, 0))
        .Add(New Media3D.Point3D(AspectRatio, 1, 0))
        .Add(New Media3D.Point3D(AspectRatio, -1, 0))
        .Add(New Media3D.Point3D(0D - AspectRatio, -1, 0))
    End With
    CType(geometryModel3D.Geometry, Media3D.MeshGeometry3D).Positions = points
End Sub
```